# Quantum Well Eigenvalues - Newton-Raphson

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, eigenvalue

The eigenvalues of a quantum well must obey:

$$\tan \left( \sqrt{\frac{a^2 m_e^* E_n}{2 \hbar^2}} \right) = \sqrt{\frac{(V_b-E_n)}{E_n}}$$

and

$$\cot \left( \sqrt{\frac{a^2 m_e^* E_n}{2 \hbar^2}} \right) = -\sqrt{\frac{(V_b-E_n)}{E_n}}$$

where $E_n$ are the eigenvalues, $V_b$ is the well's height and $a$ is the well's width.

---

I set $V_b = 1.0$ eV and I am using Newton-Raphson for solving it.

For a grid of $a$ varying from $10$ Angstrom to $300$ Angstrom, I use around 10k kick start values of $E_n$ between $-0.1$ eV and $1.1$ eV, but the algorithm diverges for some of them, resulting in this chart:

[image]

I was intending to use this values as goals or benchmark for a more robust eigenvalue solver I've been working on.

The other method happens to be more accurate than this, which should be the "analytical" solution.

Any suggestion in how to be more accurate on this method? Any idea about how to filter those noisy points maybe?

BTW. I am using [Scipy's Newton Raphson](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html)

**Edit**

I tried the same thing using the [Scipy's Brent](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html) (kindly suggested by @kyle-kanos) and I got this result:

[image]

which seems even more strange to me, now all lines are split, I wonder if this result is correct.

Comment: What's your tolerance?

Comment: Do you mean in the Scipy's function? Good question, I was not specifying this parameter.

Comment: Okay, so then it defaults to $\sim10^{-8}$, which probably won't cause that much error. Have you tried other root-finding methods (e.g., [brentq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html))?

Comment: I have tried others, but not this one, I'll give it a try ;)
Is this better than Newton-Raphson?

Comment: Answered: "Uses the classic Brent (1973) method to find a zero of the function f on the sign changing interval [a , b]. Generally considered the best of the rootfinding routines here." [brentq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html)

Comment: When you said "answered" there, was that about the question of is it better than Newton? Or was it about the post?

Comment: I am sorry, it was about Brent Q being better than Newton-Raphson.
After using this method (brentq), I got this result even more strange.